# Django: Problem deleting an Authenticated User profile

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm having problems deleting a user, where the authenticated user can delete their own account.

But what happens is that the page just refreshes, in the same template and returning '200 ok from POST'

```
[06/Aug/2022 11:46:33] "POST /members/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4998
```

**members.views.profiles.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def profile(request):
    template_name = "members/profile.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def profile_delete(request, pk):
    user_profile = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    template_name = "members/profile_delete.html"
    context = {
                  "user_profile": user_profile,
              },

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_profile.delete()
        return render(request, template_name, context)

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**members.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from allauth.account import views as allauth_views
from . import views


app_name = "members"
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", allauth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("logout/", allauth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("profile/", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("profile/<int:pk>/delete/", views.profile_delete, name="profile_delete"),
]
```

**profile.html**

```
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{ user | title }}</strong> ?</p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'members:profile_delete' user.pk %}" type="submit">
                Delete
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

---

**Solution:**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def profile(request):
    template_name = "members/profile.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def profile_delete(request, pk):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    user_profile.delete()
    template_name = "members/profile_delete.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: OK. 

I got a result.

First i changed the button, I still don't know why it's causing an incident.

but it looks like this now:
`<a class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" href="{% url 'members:profile_delete' user.pk %}">Delete</a>`

And the real issue, i found here:
def profile_delete(request, pk):
    user_profile = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    template_name = "members/profile_delete.html"
    context = {
                  "user_profile": user_profile,
              }, **<--------** (**a comma in context**)

Comment: So, you get it working without using `get_object_or_404`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're pressing your button the server sends a `GET` request, try changing the logic in your function, instead of:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Use:

```
if request.method == "GET":
```

Comment: Returning 

`[06/Aug/2022 12:21:18] "GET /members/profile/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=B43dofrWRGiLAZkBvvqbnWWWGwEnZeEj7fHtO2luRaXNjyMrPyExRjnwSLTykExJ HTTP/1.1" 200 4997`

Comment: try it without specifying any methods, i.e. remofe the `if` statement entirely

Comment: Remains the same,
**VIEW**
`def profile_delete(request, pk):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    template_name = "members/profile_delete.html"
    context = {
                  "user_profile": user_profile,
              },
    user_profile.delete()
    return render(request, template_name, context)`

Comment: you also need to do `db.session.commit()` to commit the changes in your db

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for querying single user's profile and then delete it, currently <s>`filter()`</s> makes no sense, so:

```py
user_profile=get_object_or_404(User,pk=pk)
```

`Note:` you should always return HttpResponseRedirect after dealing with POST data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good web practice in general.

Comment: I made the changes, but remains the same 

 `def profile_delete(request, pk):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    template_name = "members/profile_delete.html"
    context = {
                  "user_profile": user_profile,
              },

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_profile.delete()
        return redirect("/accounts/login/")

    return render(request, template_name, context)`